# What type of 2x4 connector is this?

Tags: connector

Each of the pins is a discrete channel/line and I would like to plug this into a breadboard - does anyone know what type of connector would let me split these out please? I know I could make a breakout board but a cable would be nice.

[image: 2x4 Connector]

Comment: Are you looking for a header socket or a bus wire with female header connector that you can plug into a breadboard?

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture without a scale reference.  It could me 0.1 inch, [2.54 mm], or 0.05 inch  [1.27mm], or 2.00 mm.  Can you measure the distance between the pins?  If not, can you provide some scale reference (for example, the width of the PCB)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a 2.54mm pin header. It is very common header, from many manufacturers.